# Find all numbers only divisible by 3, 5 and 7

Tags: math, division

I was asked on an interview to find all numbers only divisible by 3, 5 and 7. I purposed we can make check like

```
if (num%3==0 || num%5==0 || num%7==0) 
  return true 
else 
  return false.
```

But in this case if we have 6 it will pass the test but its also divisible by 2 so this doesn't work. Can you purpose something?
I am using java. Find mean to check if some number is divisible only to this number

Comment: This is the kind of question that requires you to think about the maths involved a little before diving in.

Comment: What language are you using? What code have you tried so far? How far do you want to go with your list of numbers divisible by 3, 5, and 7? (There are an infinite number of possibilities.)

Comment: What does “find” mean? Detect or list?

Comment: I am using java. Find mean to check if some number is divisible only to this numbers

Comment: Was the question specifically about prime factors? Or just an number in general?

Comment: I think your idea is pretty close but you have confused "and" and "or". What operator do you need to use to ensure the number is divisible by ALL of the factors 3, 5, and 7? I think the test you propose determines whether a number is divisible by ANY of the factors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would approach this by removing all of the factors of 3, 5, and 7 from the original number, and seeing what's left.

```
while(num % 3 == 0)
{
    num = num / 3;
}
while(num % 5 == 0)
{
    num = num / 5;
}
while(num % 7 == 0)
{
    num = num / 7;
}

return (num == 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

I won't give you a Java algorithm, as it should be fairly easy to implement.

You can just:

```
1. check if (n%3 == 0)
2. if it is, set n /= 3 and repeat step 1.
3. do the same for the number 5 and 7
4. now if n != 1, return false, else return true
```

In a Java algorithm:

```
// n is some random natural number
if (n == 1 || n == 0)
    return false

while (!n%3) 
{
    n /= 3;
}
while (!n%5)
{
    n /= 5;
}
while (!n%7)
{
    n /= 7;
}
if (n == 1)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

It's not the best syntax, I'm just giving an straight-forward implementation of the algorithm presented above.

Answer (score 2):

We first note that 1 is a member of the set. Although it is not divisible by 3, 5 or 7, neither is it divisible by any number other than 3, 5 or 7, so we will say that 1 is in the set. This conforms to the mathematical definition of the set { *x* = 3<sup>*i*</sup> · 5<sup>*j*</sup> · 7<sup>*k*</sup> | *i*, *j*, *k* ≥ 0 }.

One method is to count from 1, adding 2 at each step, and checking if the number is divisible only by 3, 5 and 7. That's slow because it does a lot of work that immediately gets discarded, since there are many fewer numbers divisible only by 3, 5 and 7 than there are odd numbers.

A better approach is to generate the desired numbers directly, by induction. The number 1 is in the set, and for any *x* in the set, so are 3 *x*, 5 *x* and 7 *x*. So the algorithm to generate all numbers divisible only by 3, 5 and 7, in order, is:

```
1. Initialize a priority queue with the number 1.
2. Pop the smallest number in the priority queue, call it x.
3. Add 3x, 5x and 7x to the priority queue.
4. Output x as the next integer in the set.
5. If you want more output, go to Step 2.
6. Halt.
```

I implemented both algorithms; you can see them at http://ideone.com/YwnAQ8. The brute-force method takes a little over ten seconds to find the 203 members of the 3,5,7 set less than a million; the priority queue does the same calculation in a hundredth of a second, a thousand times faster. The priority queue implementation used there is explained at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2009/08/14/pairing-heaps). You can also see the set of 3,5,7 numbers at [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A108347).

Comment: This is a nice approach but how would you avoid duplication
The numbers would be as follows ( The way it would be inserted in the queue ):
1 |  3 5 7 | 9 15 21 |  21 35 49 |